# Writing large amount of data to an ascii file fast in C++

Tags: c++, fwrite, cout, printf

I am writing a particle tracker in C++ which releases a particle in a numerical flow field and then integrates in time to calculate the new position of the particle.

This is done for as many particles as time allows (hopefully millions) for approximately 10k timesteps per particle. During the simulation I generate a double array1[10k][10] and int array2[10k][4] which represent the 14 characteristics of each particle at each timestep.

My question is how to write such a 'matrix' to a notepad++ readable .txt file (for the purpose of post-processing). Both arrays are to be merged in the file such that a [10k][14] matrix is formed.

Personally I have only had experience with fprintf but Visual Studio appears to have some security issues with that function. Other functions I have seen are streams (more secure I suppose) and fwrite.

Could someone enlighten what the advantages and disadvantages are of the similar functions? And possibly what the better choice is for my problem (if there is one).

Kind regards,

EJG

Comment: You title says "fast" - are you asking about speed too. That might have to be a different question.

Comment: Yes, performance is very important. For instance: I only know how to use cout by using a for loop for each element of the matrix which would be slow while fprintf can print lines I suppose.

Comment: "I only know how to use cout by using a for loop for each element of the matrix which would be slow" -- bad assumption - you should try it first - the bottleneck will almost certainly be the speed of your disk, not your code.

Comment: It will still save the line one character at a time. You might need to time different options and see what's best. The words in your question seemed just to be about which file writing functions to use, given the warning. Which way is quickest depends on your compiler and your machine

Comment: For a large amount of data like this you might find it is better to construct big chunks in memory and then write them to disk all at once.  The only way to know what works best is to profile the different options you have available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Newer Microsoft compilers give you various "security" warnings if you do not define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119578/disabling-warnings-generated-via-crt-secure-no-deprecate) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2575116/fopen-fopen-s-and-writing-to-files)

The `_s` versions it will suggest using instead are microsoft specific, so if you ever wanted to compile your code for another platform you would need to re-write.

There are other ways to write to files in C++.  You could consider using a C++ `std::ofstream` instead.

Or, you can just write to `std::cout` and stream the program output to a file

```
myprogram.exe > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use fprintf, just add `#pragma warning(disable:4996)` at the top of your source file and it won't complain about you using it.

Otherwise you can always use fprintf_s() or whatever the alternative is that VS provides.

Comment: I did solve the warning with the following:
#ifdef _WIN32
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE
#endif

But is fprintf suitable for my purpose? I know that in MATLAB it slows down scripts a lot.

Comment: Any file I/O will slow down scripts that require performance, my answer to you would be to avoid reading/writing to the file in areas where performance is key. At least that is my opinion, maybe there is a better way of going about it.

Comment: Also if you are using C++ you may look into `std::ofstream` as doctorlove suggested, as that is the C++ standard for writing to files.